# When button clicked twice do something

Tags: button

I need that when a button is clicked once it will show the message "Don't show". And when clicked twice returns to the original message "Show". The first thing I already did it, I only need help with the second thing, that being the second click.

```
function show()
{
    document.myform.button.value ="Hide";//Changes message on button when clicked.
    document.myform.button.innerHTML= "Hide";
}

<form>
<input type=button value= "Show" name="button" id= "idButton"
onClick="show()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(button)
{
    if(button.hidden)
         button.hidden = false
         document.myform.button.value ="Show";//Changes message on button when clicked.
         document.myform.button.innerHTML= "Show";
    else {
         button.hidden = true
         document.myform.button.value ="Hide";//Changes message on button when clicked.
         document.myform.button.innerHTML= "Hide";
    }
}

<form>
<input type=button value= "Show" name="button" id= "idButton"
onClick="show(this)">
</form>
```